# How to ssh and then telnet with ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssh, telnet

I need to retrieve some information from networks terminals using telnet. Those terminals are in a network, thus I cannot access that network. But I can access a server in the same network, and then telnet from there.

The case here, is that I´m doing this with ruby. I can run ruby and my program in a computer outside the network. I start coding to connect via ssh to the server, and then telnet the terminals and get the information.
I uses several libraries trying to do this, net-ssh, net-ssh-bash, and net/ssh/telnet, because I think there are the best.

```
 require 'net/ssh/telnet'
s = Net::SSH::Telnet.new(
    "Dump_log" => "/logtelnet",
    "Host" => "9.0.0.2",
    "Username" => "root",
    "Password" => "toor"
)
while 1>0
comando = gets.chomp
puts s.cmd(comando)
end
```

I can connect to the server, and I can run some commands, like "ls", "cd /" etc.

But, when I try to telnet or ssh a network terminals the session gets frozen. I cannot pipe the telnet stream into the ssh output to my program.

Any idea to solve this?